# How share data, which I get with subscribe in component, between components

Tags: json, angular, observable, subscribe

In my component I use .subscribe

```
constructor(private CityWeatherDataService: CityWeatherDataService){}

  daysForecast(city,country){

    this.CityWeatherDataService.daysForecast(city,country)
    .subscribe(data => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.humidity.push(data[i].humidity);
      } 
      return data;    
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.daysForecast("London","UK");
    console.log(this.humidity);
  }
```

My servise I did like that

```
daysForecast(city,country): Observable<WeatherItem[]>{
    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('city', city)
    .set('country', country)
    .set('key', '7fddb2fc6bae42a396f121c7bd341832');
    return this.http.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily', {params})
    .map(data=>{
      let forecastItemList = data["data"];
      return forecastItemList.map(function(forecastItem:any) {        
        return {            
          weatherDescription: forecastItem.weather.description,
          weatherIcon: forecastItem.weather.icon,
          temperature: forecastItem.temp,
          humidity: forecastItem.rh,
          wind: forecastItem.wind_spd,
          cloudiness: forecastItem.clouds,
          pressure: forecastItem.pres
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

Is it possible to use  data from .subscribe not only in this function and share for using in another component? Now when I share data from .subscribe I can only show it with ngFor in child component, but it doesn't work wtih this data in component, but I need do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndrewGumenniy, the Observables are async. That's mean that until it not finish, you have not the data. But you don't need take care about it. if your child component has an @Input, when the data change, the date is's showed in the child. You only need a variable

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-child [data]="data"></app-child>
  `
})
constructor(private CityWeatherDataService: CityWeatherDataService){}
  data:any[]; //<--your variable

  daysForecast(city,country){

    this.CityWeatherDataService.daysForecast(city,country)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data=data.map(x=>x.humidity); //<--an abreviate way to do your loop
      //you needn't return anything
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.daysForecast("London","UK");
    console.log(this.humidity); //<--this give you "null", but that's not important
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, data shows in the child template with ngFor, but I don't manipulate with it in child component, so it's  undefined

Comment: If you want to use in the same component that you subscribe, use the variable "data",e.g. in app-root write {{data}}. If you want to subscribe in a component and show in another component you can look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076225/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-service-and-observable/50076477#50076477